# Key no definido en diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hola que tal  , saben si al colocar esto de esta forma me puede arrojar una exeception ? , porque me funciona pero he visto que en otros lados recomiendan usar

```
try:
    thevariable
except NameError:
    print("well, it WASN'T defined after all!")
else:
    print("sure, it was defined.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameError` ocurre cuando ocupas una variable que no existe:

**exception NameError**

> Se genera cuando no se encuentra un nombre local o global. Esto se
> aplica solo a nombres no calificados. El valor asociado es un mensaje
> de error que incluye el nombre que no se pudo encontrar.

`KeyError` cuando intentas acceder a un diccionario usando una llave no registrada.

**exception KeyError**

> Se genera cuando no se encuentra una clave de asignación (diccionario)
> en el conjunto de claves existentes (mapa).

Probemos:

```
dicc = {}
try:
    print(hola)
except NameError:
    print("Error, variable no existe")

try:
    print(dicc["x"])
except KeyError:
    print("Error, llave inexistente")

try:
    print(dicc[hola])
except KeyError:
    print("Error, llave no existe")
except NameError:
    print("Error, variable no existe")
```

produce:

```
Error, variable no existe
Error, llave inexistente
Error, variable no existe

Process finished with exit code 0
```

El uso del diccionario puede fallar por dos condiciones: 1) la variable usada como llave no existe o 2) la variable/valor existe, pero la llave no existe en el diccionario.

Como es lógico, primero se verifica la existencia de la variable. Si no existe, produce `NameError`. Luego se verifica la existencia de la llave; si no existe, `KeyError`.

Lo normal es que la variable exista y que la llave no este registrada. Para evitar errores, usas el patrón

```
if llave in diccionario:
    # Operar con la entrada del diccionario
else:
    print("La llave no existe")
```